# Can't connect to dfs namenode web UI on remote machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed **hadoop-2.7.1** on a CentOS remote server.

Steps followed : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html *Pseudo-Distributed Operation*

I use the following command to check if the namenode web UI is open on the remote machine (commands run on the machine where hadoop is installed) :

1. `curl -s 10.41.55.16:50070 >/dev/null && echo Connected. || echo Fail.`

   Output : 
   `Connected.`

   The above curl from machine on same network gives `Fail.`

   `ping 10.41.55.16` from the machine on the same network gives desired output.
2. `netstat -a | grep 50070`

   Output : 
   `tcp        0      0 localhost:50070         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

*Some properties might be wrong or redundant in the .xml*

**etc/hadoop/core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.41.55.16:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.41.55.16:9000</value>
</property>
```

**vim etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
        <value>10.41.55.16:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.http.address</name>
        <value>10.41.55.16:50070</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Hence, http://10.41.55.16:60010/ in address bar of web browser of a machine on the same network gives no response.

Comment: Since you indicate `ping` works, have you checked the error logs on the server you are trying to access to see if there are any other errors?

Comment: @vmachan :
cat  hadoop-centos-namenode-catalog-devbox.novalocal.log | grep ERROR


 2016-01-12 12:28:24,448 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-01-12 12:30:04,755 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-01-12 12:43:51,251 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-01-12 13:09:07,097 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u using a vm? Check also firewall is not restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall status of machine where NameNode service is running:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

If status:active then stop the firewall and disable it.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl status firewalld
```